# Optimal setup for warning user before exiting screen when changes have been made

Tags: wpf

I have a user control `ProfileEditor` in a WPF application. It has a number of input controls (TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, Radio Buttons, DatePicker). It will be used to add details for a new profile, or change details for an existing profile.

There is a requirement that if any changes have been made from the initial state (blank for a new profile, prefilled with current data for existing profile), if the user tries to leave the screen, they will first be warned that there are unsaved changes. This control will always be on a `Page` inside a `Frame` element, so leaving the screen will be either when navigating to a new Page in the Frame, or exiting the application.

What is the optimal setup for this?

I am thinking that there would be some event that would be attached to all data entry controls on the page (or maybe one event per control type) on the `TextChanged` or `SelectionChanged` events that would then set a page-level `bool` property as to whether or not changes have been made. Is there a way to set these using styles for all types of a control on the page at one time?

And then how would I catch the close screen event? Attach something to the `Frame.Navigating` event?

Comment: I think you can handle the Page.LostFocus event.  As for checking for changes I would save the values when the page was loaded and compare them to the current values. User could make an edit and edit it back to the original.  Why don't you just update data from the individual controls on control LostFocus?